# Unfortunately, <application name> has stopped. (Android)

Tags: android, xml, class, android-intent

I am learning android, I am trying to develop game, I have two classes "Starter" and "Board". Starter class contains menu(http://postimg.org/image/dnyvoey2l/). Its Exit and Help buttons are working properly, but when I press "Two Player" option instead of showing board it shows an error (Unfortunately, (Application Name) has stopped). I am sharing code snippet , please suggest solution.

```
twop.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent tow= new Intent(Starter.this, Selector.class);
                startActivity(tow);

            }
        });
```

Comment: Has my solution worked for you ?

Comment: Nothing Changed. Please check the edited version. Now Starter is another class which extends activity.

Comment: Have you added Selector activity in your Manifest file ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't show `View` using `startActivity()` method

```
Intent tow= new Intent(Starter.this, Board.class);
startActivity(tow);
```

`Board` should be extended from `Activity` not from `View` class. Create an `BoardActivity.java` and extend it from `Activity`.

You should then add `Board` View either from `XML` or programmatically using `setContentView();` in your `onCreate()` method.

**Edit**

Don't forget to add new `Activity` in your `Manifest.xml` file. Like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="your.application.package.name">
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".Starter" android:label="@string/app_name"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".Selector"></activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: I changed it but problem is same yet,

Comment: No I didn't added there.

Comment: Please Check the manifest file, is it the right way to add new activity.

Comment: You should do some research before posting any basic question which can easily be answered.

Comment: You are right, I am new to android development, It was not a new problem I have seen many similar questions on stackoverflow and no one was mapping my problem, that is why I asked this question. Next time I will be careful.

Comment: You will not find exact issue in SO but you will definitely find bits and pieces which can help you out :) If my solution worked for you please mark it as a correct answer :)

Answer (score 2):

Below is my idea.
The code of OnClick means starting a new activity.

```
Intent tow= new Intent(Starter.this, Board.class);
startActivity(tow);
```

However, the Board is a View, not an activity.
So, you should make Board inherit from Activity (or create other activity to hold the Board).
When creating any activity, make sure to register in manifest.